# Object destructuring gives me a NaN value when using a specific variable name

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

My object has 2 properties, when those properties are named left and top `{ left: rect.left, top: rect.top}`.
After destructuring the object, my x and y variables are both NaN.

```
const { x, y } = this.getCanvasPosition(this.canvasHex.current);
```

But if I rename my properties of that object to x and y `{ x: rect.left, y: rect.top}`, I get the values I'm looking for.

I'm wondering what is exactly going on here.

Comment: Well there's no `x` or `y` property in your object. That's why your alternative works, because you are mapping the correct properties into `x` and `y`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment good explanation of the nature of destructuring

Comment: You could remap the properties into your desired names: https://codeshorts.com/jQuery-map%20an%20object%20changing%20property%20names

Comment: Oh wow, I was sure that I could just use any name.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a renaming of the properties, because you have no properties `x` and `y`, but `left` and `top`.

```
const { left: x, top: y } = this.getCanvasPosition(this.canvasHex.current);
```

```js
const { left: x, top: y } = { left: 10, top: 5 };

console.log(x, y);
```